# Using a URI in an MVC URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-3, uri

I'm using asp.net mvc3

I have a URL pattern like
http://mysite.com/product/{id}

Everything is fine if I use a simple id however our ids are URIs and that causes a problem.

Even when I encode the id using HttpUtility.UrlEncode MVC gives me the following error:

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

How can I make it work without simply disabling this check for everything?
And why an encoded uri is dangerous in the url anyway?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to implement your own RequestValidator and use it with your application.

The below link also has an example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.requestvalidator.aspx

Edit:

Apparently there is a way to specify what characters are invalid - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx. Setting the list to blank apparently would do the trick.   I haven't really tried this one.